# Nginx Rule -Images Not Working

Tags: nginx

My .htaccess rules;

```
RewriteRule ^img/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)  /img.php?width=$1&height=$2&src=$3&crop-to-fit [NC]
```

My Nginx Rules;

```
rewrite ^/img/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)$ /img.php?width=$1&height=$2&src=$3&crop-to-fit;
```

Nginx Working URL      : 
example.com/200/200/IMAGESFOLDER/test.jpg

Nginx Dont Working URL : 
example.com/200/200/IMAGESFOLDER/en/test.jpg

Comment: How are you using both .htaccess rules and nginx rules?    It looks like the rule passes the non-working URL through to your `img.php` script.   How does it handle it?

Comment: There is no way to tell what is wrong from what you have posted here.  Please edit the question to provide more details.

Comment: not using .htaccess. before apache used no problem .htaccess rules.